# Forward X session over SSH for an already-running program?

Tags: networking, ssh, gui, remote-desktop, x11-forwarding

I know how to forward X sessions to my local computer, and I know how to run GUIs to start on the remote machine using export `DISPLAY=:0.0`.

However, let's say I have a bittorrent client, like transmission, running on the remote machine, and I want to check on its progress? Currently, I have to run remote desktop using Remmina to check it, and this isn't ideal.

I also don't want to shut it down and then start it again on my local machine, because this will interrupt the download progress, and I will have to remember to start it again on the remote machine, once I close it locally.

So the idea is, I want to temporarily forward the X session for an already-running GUI. Is this possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you install screen:

```
sudo apt install screen
```

Then run that process through screen per this link:

[How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

You should be able to keep processes backgrounded and then bring to forground at will... I know this works for text apps, maybe for gui too.